# Creating typewriter effect on scroll. One section will work, the other will not! JavaScript, HTML, CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am working on my website and I have added a Typewriter effect on scroll, it will work in one section of the page, when I go to duplicate the code for the next section, on the execution of the script it will give an error.

This is the entire script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                s = $("body").scrollTop();
                h = 150;
                console.log(s);
                if(s>150)
                {
                    text1.ready();
                }
                if(s>600)
                {
                    text2.ready();
                }
            });

            $(document).ready(function(){

            });
            var text1 = {
                counter:0,
                count:0,
                value:"",
                subvalue:"",
                start:0,
                ready:function()
                {

                    if(text1.start==0)
                    {
                        text1.start = 1;
                        data_text = $(".data-text");
                        data_text.css({left:0, opacity:1});
                        text1.counter = $(".data-text").data("text").length-34;
                        console.log(text1.counter);
                        text1.value = $(".data-text").data("text");
                        var str = text1.value;
                        text1.subvalue = str.substr(0,34);
                        data_text.html(text1.subvalue).append('<span class="cursor">|</span>');
                        var text1_engine = setInterval(function(){
                                if(text1.counter>0)
                                {
                                    text1.counter = text1.counter-1;
                                    text1.count = text1.count+1;
                                    text1.subvalue = str.substr(0, 34)+str.substr(34,text1.count);
                                    data_text.html(text1.subvalue).append('<span class="cursor">|</span>');
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //text1 = false;
                                    clearInterval(text1_engine);
                                    console.log(1);
                                }
                        }, 50);
                    }
                }

            };
            var text2 = {
                counter:0,
                count:0,
                value:"",
                subvalue:"",
                start:0,
                ready:function()
                {
                    if(text2.start==0)
                    {
                        text2.start = 1;
                        steps_text = $(".steps-text");
                        steps_text.css({left:0, opacity:1});
                        text2.counter = $(".steps-text").data("text").length-34;
                        console.log(text2.counter);
                        text2.value = $(".steps-text").data("text");
                        var str = text2.value;
                        text2.subvalue = str.substr(0,34);
                        steps_text.html(text2.subvalue).append('<span class="cursor">|</span>');
                        var text_engine = setInterval(function(){
                                if(text2.counter>0)
                                {
                                    text2.counter = text2.counter-1;
                                    text2.count = text2.count+1;
                                    text2.subvalue = str.substr(0, 34)+str.substr(34,text2.count);
                                    steps_text.html(text2.subvalue).append('<span class="cursor">|</span>');
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //text2 = false;
                                    clearInterval(text2_engine);
                                    console.log(1);
                                }
                        }, 50);
                    }
                }

            };
```

Here is the HTML for text1 which is working:

```
<h1 class="data-text" data-text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eu odio massa nunc."></h1>
```

Now in a different section my text2 is not working:

```
<h1 class="steps-text" steps-text="Integer sit am..."></h1>
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
(index):140 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Comment: May I know what error you are receiving?

Comment: I just added the error:
`(index):140 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: Try changing your text2 html as `<h1 class="data-steps-text" steps-text="Integer sit am..."></h1>` and see if it works.

Comment: Experiencing the same issues.If need be I can add the link to the live site.

Comment: Can you please give me a link to check the output?

Comment: Try changing the line from `text2.counter = $(".steps-text").data("text").length-34;` to `text2.counter = $(".steps-text").attr('steps-text')-34;`

Comment: We are making some progress. I have updated the code It looks like the style sheet is change it is still not displaying anything. It is throwing another error.

Is it due to the fact that it is short and does not have a second line?
This is the new error:
`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'str.substr')`

Comment: I fixed this by doing the same thing you told me to do on the other line. I think I can get it to scroll now, just by changing the 34 to something lower!

`text2.value = $(".steps-text").attr("steps-text");`

Comment: If you visit the page now the problem now is that the text isn't actually doing the animation, no error seem to be thrown up..

Comment: Cool.. Glad that it is working now!

Comment: Well, the full text appear, but the text animation doesn't work. I know you've already helped so much, I can literally see the finish line, but I just can't get there myself, I'm just not proficient enough in jQuery to understand..

Comment: Just checked the live page at, http://premium-wp.org/ It doesn't seem to have your recent changes. Can you please upload all the changes and let me know?

Comment: I updated the code little bit, i went with the .data instead of .attr, I'm getting the same exact effect with both

Comment: So, It is working now right?

Comment: No, I meant the same effect as in, the full sentence just appears, versus scrolling in. The effect in box-1 is working, but not box-2 where it says "how it works"

Comment: "How it works" is relatively a small sentence, hence the animation may get over before you scroll down and see it

Comment: I sent the  

`if(s>1150)
     {
      text2.ready();
     }`

So it doesn't  start until you scroll for a while

Comment: I have exactly placed my screen on the **How it works** section and hit the CTRL+R keys to refresh that, and waited for the timer to finish, and nothing happened even after waiting for 2 mins, However when I clicked on the screen the text appeared without any animation effect.

Comment: Thats the effect I am getting, however the code is no different then the one above it.. but in the first section it is working perfectly fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by either switching it to attr("CLASS") or by giving it it's own tag:

```
var text2 = {
                counter:0,
                count:0,
                value:"",
                subvalue:"",
                start:0,
                ready:function()
                {
                    if(text2.start==0)
                    {
                        text2.start = 1;
                        data_stext = $(".data-stext");
                        data_stext.css({left:0, opacity:1});
                        text2.counter = $(".data-stext").data('stext').length-4;
                        console.log(text2.counter);
                        text2.value = $(".data-stext").data('stext');
                        var str = text2.value;
                        text2.subvalue = str.substr(0,4);
                        data_stext.html(text2.subvalue).append('<span class="cursor">|</span>');
                        var text2_engine = setInterval(function(){
                                if(text2.counter>0)
                                {
                                    text2.counter = text2.counter-1;
                                    text2.count = text2.count+1;
                                    text2.subvalue = str.substr(0, 4)+str.substr(4,text2.count);
                                    data_stext.html(text2.subvalue).append('<span class="cursor">|</span>');
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //text2 = false;
                                    clearInterval(text2_engine);
                                    console.log(2);
                                }
                        }, 50);
                    }
                }

            };
```

And by:

```
<h1 class="data-stext" data-stext="How It Works..."></h1>
```